# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7, Size:7

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am creating a program that finds the solutions to the eight queens problem by breadth search. My code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;  

public class EightQueens {
public static void main(String[ ] args) {

    ArrayList<List<Integer>> states = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> start=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int s=0; s<8; s++) {
        start.add(0);
    }
    states.add(start);

    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int j=1; j<9; j++) {

        a = states.get(0);
        states.remove(0);

        if (j==1) {

            for (int n=1; n<9; n++) {
                a.set(0,n);
                states.add(a);  
            }
        }

        else {

            for (int i=j-1; i>0; i--) {
                b.add(a.get(i-1));
                b.add(a.get(i-1)-1);
                b.add(a.get(i-1)+1);
            }

            for (int n=0; n<8; n++) {
                List<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                for (int t=1; t<9; t++) {
                    c.add(t);
                }

                for (int k=0; k<b.size(); k++) {
                    if (c.get(n)== b.get(k)) {
                        c.remove(n);
                    }
                }
                for (int r=0; r<c.size(); r++) {
                    if (c.get(r)==n+1) {
                        a.set(j-1,n+1);
                        states.add(a);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

    for (int m=0; m< states.size(); m++) {
        a = states.get(0);
        for (int p=0; p< a.size(); p++) {
            int q = a.get(p);
            System.out.print(q);
        }
        states.remove(a);
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    int numsol = states.size();
    System.out.println(numsol);
}
}
```

This compiles without any errors, but when I go to run the program I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutofBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7
   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(Arraylist.java:411)
   at EightQueens.main(EightQueens.java:48)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you think the error means? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Look at the error message it gave you: `Index: 7, Size: 7` Now keep in mind that index numbering starts at 0 and you should find what's wrong!

Comment: Is that your exact code? The line your exception is telling you corresponds to the code you posted above?

Answer (score 3):

Java uses 0 for the first index, not one.  Adjust your program accordingly and it will work.  If you have 7 items in an array you use 0-6, not 1-7.

Also, use descriptive names for your variables.  a, b, m, x, etc are just bad.

Comment: Actually if you look at the line which causes the error, he accesses 8 elements of `c` (starting at 0), but he also added 8 before

Comment: Perhaps it's from a decompilation. Who in their right minds would use alphabets as var names?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:

```
if (c.get(n)== b.get(k)) {
    c.remove(n);
}
```

You are iterating over your `b` list and probably remove an element from `c` when `n` is 7, so you end up with only 7 elements in `c` and therefore an OutOfBoundsException.

What you wanna do is to add a `break` that the iteration stops once so you have deleted the element:

```
if (c.get(n)== b.get(k)) {
    c.remove(n);
    break;
}
```

This should fix it.